# Changes & to &amp; in php class

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `Laravel 5.2` and i just created simply class where I creating web request to receive a json file.

So the part of class looks like:

```
public function request(){
    $request = 'https://example.com/someotherthings/var='.$value1.'&var2='.$value2';
}
```

In response i get :

```
https://example.com/someotherthings/var=valueOfValue1&amp;var2=valueOfValue2
```

The problem is that request is wrong and i don't got response in return.

Comment: Have you tried `urlencode`? Here you have the documentation: http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last quote mark:

```
$request = 'https://example.com/someotherthings/var='.$value1.'&var2='.$value2';
```

Becomes:

```
$request = 'https://example.com/someotherthings/var='.$value1.'&var2='.$value2;
```

Then to be safe encode the url:

```
$urlEncodedRequest = urlencode($request);
```